# CheckBoxList not passing values when not Visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following CheckBoxList in asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cat_comp" runat="server" DataSourceID="cats_point_calc" 
DataTextField="cats_points" DataValueField="cats_points" Visible="false"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And the following C# to auto select all checkboxes on an OnClick method;

```
foreach (ListItem li in cat_comp.Items)
        {
            li.Selected = true;
        }

        int catselected = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cat_comp.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cat_comp.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                string catval = cat_comp.Items[i].Value;
                catselected += int.Parse(catval);
            }
        }
```

When I set `cat_comp` `Visible` to `true` this code works fine, is there a method to pass these values without the user being able to view this CheckBoxList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you set the `Visible` property of an ASP.NET server control, that particular control is not rendered, and thus you will not be able to calculate the value.

You can instead set the `display:none` style (or add a class) so that the control will be hidden but you can make the calculations, like this:-

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cat_comp" runat="server" CssClass="DisplayNone"

<style>
  .DisplayNone { display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.